# Linear dependence when number of vectors is greater than/less than the dimensions of the vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, combinations

Simple question here, I just need some clarification of a theorem.

Theorem: if $k > n$, then any $k$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ are linearly dependent.

Nice and easy I guess! My question is this: Does this imply that, if $k \leq n$, the system is linearly independent?

Comment: No. If $\;k\le n\;$ it means the set of vectors *has a chance* of being linearly independent, but it can be that it is linearly dependent.

Comment: This is a typical example of denying the antecedent, also called inverse error or fallacy of the inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true. Pick as an example $[1,0,0]^T,[2,0,0]^T $, which are two linearly dependent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$